Bounded Star Height and corresponding fragments of MSO
The generalized star height of a regular language is defined as the maximal number of nested Kleene-stars in a regular expression (with union, concatenation, complement, and Kleene-stars) that recognizes the language.
The Schützenberger theorem famously states that for a regular language $L$, the following conditions are equivalent:

$L$ has star height $0$ (i.e. regular expressions without Kleene-star),
$L$ is recognized by a first order logic (FO) formula, and
the syntactic monoid of $L$ is aperiodic.

Where point (2) is attributed to McNaughton-Papert.
Is there a generalization of this equivalence between (1) and (2) for languages with bounded star height and a specific fragment of MSO? It seems intuitive that this would correspond to MSO formulas with a bounded number of nested monadic quantifiers, but I have not been able to find such correspondences in the literature.

It is known that every regular language can be defined by a purely existential MSO formula, so the quantifier rank hierarchy of MSO on words has only two levels $0$ and $1$. A proof of this can, e.g., be found in the book "Finite Automata, Formal Logic, and Circuit Complexity" by Howard Straubing.
On the other hand, it is an open problem whether the generalized star-height hierarchy is infinite, or even whether there exists regular languages that require generalized star-height greater than $1$. So there does not seem to be a known correspondence between the two hierarchies.

Thanks, I also found the collapse being mentioned in the introduction of this work. To be precise, I think the correspondence could still hold right? In that case there would be no languages of star-height 2. However, this does answers that it is probably not known in literature.

You're right, I edited the answer accordingly
